# How to Upload and Save Files Using Selenium in Team City server with C#

Tags: java, javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem in running a test in Team city server which contains a file upload, the dialog box opens and not getting closed. While running locally I use the code "**DECLUPD.DeclarationUpd.SendKeys("c:\PreClearance.doc");**" 
it works fine and the same code in team city server not working and getting the error 
"**Test(s) failed. OpenQA.Selenium.UnhandledAlertException : Modal dialog present at 
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError (Response errorResponse)**"

I use asp.net 3.5 framework and the selenium driver version 2.39.